# How to create a Contact associated with an Account by external ID?

Tags: rest-api, account, contact, relationships

I'm trying to create a `Contact` trough a REST API. I want it to be linked with an `Account`. At this point I don't know the `AccountId`, however, I do know a value of `ext_id__c` which is a custom field marked as External ID.

Associating objects with external IDs works fine for custom relationships. It's documented here: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_upsert.htm
I can't figure out how to achieve the same for the build-in relationship between Contact and Account. I have tried several approaches:

- `AccountId: "<ext_id>"`
- `AccountId: { ext_id__c: "<ext_id>" }`
- `AccountId__r: { ext_id__c: "<ext_id>" }`
- `AccountId.ext_id__c: "<ext_id>"`
- `AccountId_ext_id__c: "<ext_id>"`
- `AccountId: "ext_id__c/<ext_id>"`

All attempts failed with an error complaining about malformed id or no such column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally figured it out. When you want to associate a Contact with an Account using an external ID than it should be passed in this way:

```
Account: { ext_id__c: "<ext_id>" }
```

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, for me it's not working this formate "Account: { ext_id__c: "<ext_id>" }"  Could you please post your entire JSON and REST URL

Comment: @Nishadkallingal Unfortunately, I have no longer access to the code.

Answer (score 0):

you need to do do it like this:

{
...
"account": { "yourexternalid":"value" },
...
}

only for the case the you're going to relate a custom object you'd need to use the custom objects name instead. Due to that you're going to a related attribute of account you're using "account" instead of "accountid", like you're doing it in relationship queries.